# is there a solution for accessing the first item in a recyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, showcaseview, user-guide

I'm creating a user guide and one of my items that I want to describe in my user Guide is in my recycler View help me please I'm using this library : `com.github.mreram:showcaseview:1.2.0`

found the solution:

```
private var isPlayed = false
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.onFill(holder.adapterPosition)
    if (position == 0 && !isPlayed) {
        holder.guide()
        isPlayed = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question and include the code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access recyclerview's first item by checking position of t he item in onBindview method

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(position==0)
     // write your code here
    else
     // other code
   }
```